# How to unit test Response.Redirect?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, unit-testing, testing

I need to test my controller which does Response.Redirect() at the last line. But in that moment the Response object is null. What I need to do to unit test it?
I don't use NUnit or other tools but built-in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not nearly enough information for a specific answer, but here's some information that might be useful.

First off, I'll assume your controller returns ActionResult, which is a base class for all the actual results, including System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult. RedirectResult has a property called Url which is what you need to test.

Secondly, from what I can understand, your Response object is null, probably because your testing environment/setup does not initialise it. You should consider using a mocking library to help you out on that, such as Moq.

Comment: thank you! Now i change Response.Redirect to return Redirect(..) and it works fine!